# не работает click в canvas

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas, события, click

Есть img в canvas! Поворачиваю на Math.PI / 3 (60 град.) Ctx.rotate () - поворачивается !!! Вешаю событие щелкни по холсту - ничего не происходит !? В чем дело ???

```
let dest = Math.PI / 3;
let  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawImg() {      
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    let myImage = new Image();
    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    myImage.src = dataURL;
    myImage.onload = function(){// onload отрисовываем после загрузки image
      ctx.save();
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);//restore scale;
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
}

function rotate() {       
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height/2);
  ctx.rotate(dest);
  ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height/2); 
  drawImg();             
}

rotate(); //работает
canvas.onclick = function() {rotate();}// не работает????
canvas.addEventListener("click", rotate);// не работает????
```

Comment: Это не полный код, и он работает, если почистить его от мусора, единственное что могло пойти не так, на мой взгляд, это то - что первоначально нарисовано на канве? картинка? тогда я полагаю что проблема в `myImage.crossOrigin = true;`

Comment: изначально я обрезал img в canvas  методом ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in'; потом пытаюсь кликом повернуть то, что получилось в canvas на 60 град. Вижу никаких проблем у Chrome нет с простым вызовом rotate(), а при click происходит нарушением same origin policy? Причем по toDataURL  img  берется из canvas в браузере,а не из локальной машины!?

Comment: я сначала сделал код для ответа, а потом написал коммент, опубликовал ответ, глядите сами

Comment: в любом случае спасибо...щас буду локальный сервер настраивать)))

Answer (score 1):

```js
let dest = Math.PI / 6;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let myImage = new Image();
myImage.crossOrigin = true;
myImage.src = 'https://picsum.photos/300/150';
myImage.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
}

function drawImg() {      
  let myImage = new Image();
  let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  myImage.src = dataURL;
  myImage.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
  }
}

function rotate() {       
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height/2);
  ctx.rotate(dest);
  ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height/2); 
  drawImg();             
}

canvas.addEventListener("click", rotate);
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas ></canvas>
```

Comment: Вставил перед img.src  в консоли вижу вот это:" Access to image at 'file:///D:/2020/%D.......from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: На мониторе пустой canvas

Comment: @Эйссер пример в сниппете работает?

Comment: Да работает, но мой myImage.src = "images/blabla.jpg"; на локалке, а ваш myImage.src = 'https://picsum.photos/300/150'; сетевой((( CORS мой не принимает(((((есть какой нибудь crossOrigin для такого случая?

Comment: без локального сервера ничего не получится, или загрузите картинку на хостинг типа Imgur

Comment: на openserver исчезла ошибка CORS , стало ясно что click не работает из за метода globalCompositeOperation!? Пересечение фигур вращается простым rotate!? Почему?

Comment: у меня вот такая конструкция: есть сtx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0); затем идет ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in'; пересечение с кругом. При rotate(); вся конструкция поворачивается на угол, при canvas.addEventListener("click", rotate);  нет!? Загадка canvas!!! Почему?

Comment: @Эйссер может все таки Вы соберете воспроизводимый пример?